# Switching between span tabs to display different Iframe HTML error

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs, electron

I'm building an electron app and I created a div menu with spans in it that contain their own Iframe HTML. I want to be able to click on a specific span and for it to display its Iframe. Right now when I have more than one Iframe in the HTML file, it displays them over each other. Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
    <img src="./images/group-30.png" class="logo"></img>

    <span class="menu_spans" id="tasks">
        <img src="images/group-47.png" class="tasks-img"></img>
        <!--<iframe src="tasks.html"></iframe>-->  
    </span>

    <span class="menu_spans" id="add-tasks">
        <img src="images/group-55.png" class="add-tasks-img">
        <iframe src="addTasks.html" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="yes" style="width:1020px; height: 574px; position: relative; top:-350%; left: 57px; border:none;"></iframe>
    </span>

    <span class="menu_spans" id="billing">
        <img src="images/group-60.png" class="billing-img">
        <!--<iframe src="billing.html" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="yes" style="width: 1020px; height: 574px; position: relative; top:-269px; left: 57px; border: none;"></iframe>-->
    </span>

    <span class="menu_spans" id="proxies">
        <img src="images/group-61.png" class="proxies-img">
        <!--<iframe src=""></iframe>-->
    </span>

 etc...
```

I've tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
let menu_spans = document.querySelectorAll(".menu_spans");

for (var i = 0; i < menu_spans.length; i++) {
    menu_spans[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log(this.id);
    });
}
```

I've coded this before in jQuery a while ago but im not sure how to do it in just regular js.

Any help is appreciated thank you!

Comment: what do you mean by '...it displays them over each other'? That would be more of a css problem i guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
let menu_spans = document.querySelectorAll(".menu_spans");

for (var i = 0; i < menu_spans.length; i++) {
  menu_spans[i].addEventListener('click', smth, false);
}

function smth() {
  console.log(this.id);
}
```

Comment: works but how can I stop from iframes overlapping each other and only displaying when its span is selected and for background color to change of selected span?

Answer (score 0):

Here is JavaScript code which properly reads id of clicked element, so you can use the id of element to set iframe thing in future.

```
let menu_spans = document.querySelectorAll(".menu_spans");

for (var i = 0; i < menu_spans.length; i++) {
    menu_spans[i].addEventListener('click', (event) => {
           if (event.currentTarget.nodeName === "SPAN") {
           console.log(event.currentTarget.id);
            return true;
           }
    });
}
```

Link to fiddle: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/agorgon/op6uwcmt/16/)

Comment: works but how can I stop from iframes overlapping each other and only displaying when its span is selected and for background color to change of selected span?